# Can I use a real service within a test for another service?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have an angularJS application that has two services.  I'm using one of the services (CONSTANT) to just return codes that stored based on a name.  I'm using this so that my code is more readable and I can use something like CONSTANT.APPLE rather than the code for 'apple' which might be 7898734.  I'm using Karma to test a service that uses the CONSTANT service within itself.  Thus far I've just been mocking the CONSTANT service like this:

```
    CONSTANT = {
        APPLE: 564,
        BANANA: 566,
        KIWI: 577,
        PINEAPPLE: 522455013
    };

    $provide.value('CONSTANT', CONSTANT);
```

But as I'm adding more tests I'm pretty much just duplicating my entire CONSTANT service inside of my test.  Is there any way that I can inject a the real CONSTANT service into my test instead of creating a mock for it?

I have tried just injecting it like I would in the real service:

```
describe('ServiceToTest', ['CONSTANT', function (CONSTANT) {...}]);
```

but I get this error from Karma:

```
Uncaught Error: describe does not expect a done parameter
```

Comment: the dependencies are usually injected in beforeEach() function not describe(). there are some examples available on https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

Comment: I see it now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in my code but not for constants. You can just create an auxiliary file in your test folder and in the file, create a normal angular service and then inject that service in your tests.

What you could also do is instead of having your constants in a service, define them in the app module, so every time you use that module, you will have them.
You can do something like:

```
angular
    .module('main', [])
    .constant('FruitConstants', {
        APPLE: 564,
        BANANA: 566,
        KIWI: 577,
        PINEAPPLE: 522455013
    })
//The rest of your module
```

And then in the service where you have to use them you just inject the "FruitConstants" as if they were another service:

```
 angular
    .module('main')
    .service("SomeService", someService);

someService.$inject = ['FruitConstants'];

 function someService(FruitConstants){
     //Your service logic    
}
```